Flutter OpenContainer plus Hero animation
I am trying to achieve an animation which mixes both the OpenContainer from Flutter's animations package, but it doesn't seem to support Hero animations. There are also multiple issues asking for it on GitHub without much progress, so I was wondering how I would go about creating a custom solution. I specifically want the animation in this GIF below where it is a simple button that expands to fill the whole screen, but with an extra Hero animation.
